# how to use the streamsocket as a non-blocking tcp client in the poco library?

Tags: c++, tcp, client, poco, nonblocking

the poco library provides a reactor framework for tcp server. and there are some samples demonstrated how to use it.

but I couldnot find any example of the streamsocket. I just want to use it in the tcp client with non-blocking mode, how to use it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation for networking I/O in C++ is to use [**ASIO**](http://think-async.com/) as it is being prepared for inclusion within the C++ language standard.